# How to customize right click option in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox with content. I just need like,when I select the text and right click, the appropriate ( reference) list should be displayed as pop up based on the selected text.

For example. In the article, there would be "This is referred by (williams, 2012)".
If I select Williams and right click , the reference list with the name williams should be listed as popup.

javascript code:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
Lorem ipsum...
</body>
```

This code is from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhvv6/)

Right now, am just with this code only I don't have any idea how to build it to my requirement.When right click with the selected text how to pop up the appropriate list.
Pls help!

Comment: `http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-html5-context-menus`

 `http://livepipe.net/control/contextmenu`

Comment: Just create/show an element containig the list. You can calculate position of that element using some properties of [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

Comment: It's annoying to mess with the context menu, consider using hover or a hot spot to pop–up the information instead.

Comment: just I need some start-up program for my requirement as am beginner in javascript,So can you pls let me know any  relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this.

```js
function customContextAction(e){
    var posX = e.x || e.clientX || e.layerX || e.offsetX || e.pageX, //gets the event position X
     posY=e.y || e.clientY || e.layerY || e.offsetY || e.pageY;  //gets the event position Y
    var selectedText=window.getSelection().toString() || "";
    var ctx = document.getElementById('context');
    if (ctx.className.toLowerCase().indexOf("hidden") >= 0){
     ctx.className="";
     ctx.setAttribute('style', 'top:'+posY+"px;"+"left:"+posX+"px");
    if(selectedText!="")    ctx.children[0].innerHTML=selectedText;
    }
    else{
     ctx.className="hidden";
     customContextAction(e);
    }
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        customContextAction(e);
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function(e){
        customContextAction(e);
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
}
```

```css
#context {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #cacaca;
}
#context.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#context .inner {}
```

```html
Select something and right click anywhere!
<div id="context" class="hidden">
  <div class="inner">
    CONTEXT CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```